# Gradle in command line or Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Android studio provides lots of plugins and features to run the task more quickly. There are two ways to run Android applications that I know,

1. Download [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install) and run in cmd. (Without Android Studio)
2. In Android Studio generally, all developers do in this way.

I know the major differences. Can we run below tasks without Android Studio and with installed Gradle and in CMD.

E.g.

1. I want to clean build in cmd without Android Studio.
2. Generate signed APK in CMD.
3. Run test cases in CMD.

Make sure to run above tasks there will not be any dependency on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways are totally the same.

Also, with Gradle, you do not run Android applications. Gradle is your build tool which has a plugin for build steps necessary for Android applications. Android Studio offers you an integration of the mentioned build tool, but you are free to use this integration or a standalone Gradle installation.

However, take care about different versions of Gradle, this may cause your build files to only work with either the standalone or the Android Studio Gradle installation. Also, it may be possible, that the two installations do not share temporal folders or global properties, as they expect them in different directories.

For my part, I use the Android Studio Gradle installation with the tool integration, but switch to a standalone installation for continouus runs (e.g. a Gretty container).